# Installing wordpress and laravel in the same database because my hosting doesn't allow multiple databases

Tags: database, wordpress, laravel

I have existing **Laravel** website up and running at https://iqtestsite.com/ . I want to install a blog section for this website using **wordpress**. When i try one click installation, it shows an error that `database already exist`.

My Domain can only have one database, i currently have important data on the server. I can't lose any part of the data.

How should i proceed here.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Your question looks off-topic for Stack Overflow _ Check out the top 2 FAQs in SO Help Section section on 'Asking' >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking _ As the issue is specific to the setup on your webhost it's more likely they will be more able to help you _ Good Luck

Comment: Install the WordPress in your localhost and import the DB to your existing DB. then you can change your wp-config.php file manually cording to your DB details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is off-topic still I'll try to answer your question.
put the Wordpress Blog in the 'public' folder of your Laravel app.

i.e. .../laravel_app/public/wordpress_blog

or simply: laravel_app/public/blog

you can access the blog at https://www.your-site.com/blog

you can access the admin at https://www.your-site.com/blog/wp_admin

no need to worry about the routes in laravel, it will work just fine.

**You can use the same database for both, just use a prefix for the WordPress tables e.g. 'wp_table_name'. you can set a prefix during WordPress installation. So you have a single database for both Laravel & Wordpress tables.**

Answer (score 1):

In WordPress table prefix write  wp2_

rest all you can put as same as before...

I guess it will work...

the restriction is always on the database, not tables... so add tables same as woocoomerce / wordfence and other olugin insert own tables in your database... so you can incert your tables in old database